# Project Scorpius. Can similar goals be pursued with diamond anvil cells?

Tags: experimental-technique, states-of-matter

I just read an article describing the [project Scorpius](https://spectrum.ieee.org/nuclear-weapons-testing). The aim is to use explosives to compress and heat microscopic quantities of Plutonium in order to study the states of the matter in extreme conditions.

I wondered why they needed to recreate those conditions with explosions. Couldn't they achieve the same states with a [Diamond anvil cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_anvil_cell)? With such apparatus they could compress a microscopic quantity to more than a million atmospheres and by passing some laser pulses trough the diamond anvils they could heat the matter.

Am I missing something about the project purpose?

Comment: Scorpius does not deal with microscopic quantities of Pu.